# How do I use Dataflow with my existing maven project?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What dependencies and other modifications do I need to make to my pom file so that I can start using the Dataflow SDK with my existing project?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following dependency to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <version>[0.3.141216,)</version>
</dependency>
```

The [0.3.141216,) syntax means maven will pull in the latest version as long as its more recent than 0.3.141216. This means we will automatically stay up to date as the Dataflow team publishes updates to maven central.

If we don't want to automatically upgrade to the latest SDK every time we rebuild we can specify the version as

```
<version>0.3.141216</version>
```